# cs0553 user-defined conversion from base class not allowed

Tags: c#, type-conversion

What I really want to achieve: Introduce a global alias name for `object`.

As there are no global aliases in C# I want to workaround that by providing another class `myclass` to which all objects are implicitly convertable, e.g.:

```
myclass foo () { return new object(); } // should be ok
myclass bar () { return "bla"; } // should be ok
```

How to?

(a conversion operator:

```
    public static implicit operator myclass(object o)
    {
        return new given();
    }
```

just outputs compiler error cs0553)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't do that. From section 10.10.3 of the C# 4 specification:

> A class or struct is permitted to declare a conversion from a source type `S` to a target type `T` only if all of the following are true:
>
> - ...
> - Exclusing user-defined conversions, a conversion does not exist from `S` to `T` or from `T` to `S`

That's not true in your case, hence the error.

You haven't said *why* you want to do this (you mention "no global aliases" but it's not clear what you're trying to achieve), but you just can't do this. You could create a constructor or a static method to create an instance of your class, but you can't do it with an operator.

Comment: The more I use C#, the more often I find weaknesses (no global type aliasing in this case...). Is there any other workaround for my problem?

Comment: @D.R.: No, because we really don't know what you mean by "no global type aliasing" here. What are you really trying to achieve? What benefit would this give you? It doesn't look like anything I've ever wanted to do - and it looks like the language designers don't expect you to want to do this either. In general it's a bad idea to fight the language like this.

Comment: We're API designers for specification frameworks (like MSpec) and want to distinguish given/when methods by its return type. Unfortunately you can't alias given/when for void and find "given" and "when" at runtime via Reflection. Therefore we introduced own classes. when is an enum, however, a given-method should return the subject under test - an object of some type T we don't really know.

Comment: Actually we know the type T (generic parameter of the spec test class). However...doesn't help the case much...

Comment: @D.R.: I'm afraid you clearly have more context than we have - your explanation may make sense to you, but it means very little to me. You should expand on it in your question, but either way you simply can't do this.

Comment: Guess I'm creating a new question, thanks for the clarification on this specific one though!

Comment: Jon Skeet: If you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459547/distinguishing-methods-at-runtime-by-return-type