# Distinguishing methods at runtime by return type

Tags: c#, type-conversion

We're developing something like a Spec-framework (e.g. MSpec, NSpec, etc.) and want to distinguish methods within a specification class at runtime:

```
public class AccountSpecs
{
    private Account sut; // subject under test

    Given an_account() { sut = new Account(); }

    When changing_owner()
    {
        var result = sut.ChangeOwner("new owner");
        It["returns_previous_owner"] = () => result.ShouldBe("old owner");
    }
}
```

As you can see this class is not compileable because an_account() and changing_owner() do not have return statements.

Q1: I guess there is absolutely no way in C# to specify that "return null" is used by default if no return statement is given?

As there are no global type aliases (something like `typedef When as System.Void`) we are forced to actually introduce the classes Given and When and force our users to return something in this methods.

We use the return statement in the When methods for either `When.ENABLED` or `When.DISABLED("reason")` to temporarily disable specs.

In the "given methods" we want to return the subject under test. We want to enable the following:

```
Given an_account() { sut = new Account(); return sut; }
```

However: "Cannot convert expression type ... to return type ..."

Next up we thought about an implicit conversion operator for any object to Given, however this isn't allowed in C# either, see: [cs0553 user-defined conversion from base class not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459233/cs0553-user-defined-conversion-from-base-class-not-allowed)

Q2: So is there any workaround for this to work or is the return-type-distinguishing-idea doomed?

Comment: It sounds like you need to design your own language.

Comment: There are others who did this, e.g. SpecFlow, however, we think that creating our own DSL drastically reduces user acceptance of a framework.

Comment: Please do your future self a favour and choose better class names (when/given/shouldbe), otherwise are you after [Default?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx)

Comment: when/given are perfectly sane class names in the given context. ShouldBe is an extension method from the very famous FluentAssertions project.

Comment: No, default does not prevent our users from writing boilerplate return statements.

Comment: Consider whether creating a graphical DSL would improve acceptance. See [Visualization and Modeling SDK - Domain-Specific Languages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126259.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, we already evaluated our options. We're going to make the best out of this one. SOF is no discussion board, so please stay on topic, thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of options if you change your design a little.

1. You can add a porperty to Given type that will hold a refernce to any object, so that an_account will `return Given(sut)`
2. You can return plain object from an_account and mark the method with `[Given]` attribute
3. You can also get rid of this method-in-the-class approach and just use a builder pattern with fluent interface, like linq, to create a test definition.

Like this:

```
new Test()
    .Given(() =>new Account())
    .When(()=> ...);
```

Comment: Thanks. It's not really an answer as there seems to be no such thing to my question, but I guess this is the next best thing.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but it got me playing with the code. Not sure if this was available back then but following should work.

```
public class AccountSpecs {
    private Account sut; // subject under test

    Given<Account> an_account() => sut = new Account();
    Given an_account2() => (Given<Account>)(sut = new Account());

    When changing_owner => () => {
        var result = sut.ChangeOwner("new owner");
        It["returns_previous_owner"] = () => result.ShouldBe("old owner");
    };
}

public class Given {
    public readonly object o;
    public Given(object o) => this.o = o;
}
public class Given<T> : Given {
    new public T o => (T)base.o;
    public Given(object o) : base(o) {}
    public static implicit operator Given<T>(T t)
        => new Given<T>(t);

}

public delegate void When();
```

This version of `changing_owner` is probably closest you can get to the original version in terms of no return statement, although it's a property here.

As an extra I crafted following (never runned):)

```
using System;
using static audionysos.gui.Specifier;

namespace audionysos.gui;

public class AccountSpecs {
    private Account s; // subject under test

    public AccountSpecs() {
        givenSubject(s = new Account())
            .method(s.ChangeOwner)
                .returns("old owner").whenGiven("new owner");
    }
}

public static class Specifier {

    internal static SubjectContext current;
    public static SubjectContext<T> givenSubject<T>(T obj) {
        var x = new SubjectContext<T>(obj);
        current = x;
        return x;
    }

    public static M method<M>(this object o, M m) where M : Delegate {
        return m;
    }

    public static MethodTestContext<T, R> returns<T, R>(this Func<T, R> t, R r) {
        return new MethodTestContext<T, R>(t, r);
    }

}

public class SubjectContext {
    internal void register<T, R>(MethodTestContext<T, R> methodTestContext) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class SubjectContext<T> : SubjectContext {
    public T its { get; }
    public SubjectContext(T t) {
        this.its = t;
    }
}

public abstract class MethodTestContext {
    protected abstract bool test();
}
public class MethodTestContext<T, R> : MethodTestContext {
    private T arg;
    private readonly Func<T, R> m;

    public MethodTestContext<T, R> whenGiven(T arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
        return this;
    }

    protected override bool test() {
        var r = m(arg);
        if (r == null && expectedReturn == null) return true;
        if (r == null || expectedReturn == null) return false;
        return r.Equals(expectedReturn);
    }

    internal R expectedReturn { get; }

    public MethodTestContext(Func<T, R> m, R r) {
        this.m = m;
        this.expectedReturn = r;
        Specifier.current.register(this);
    }
}
```

I also think this is much more readable. I was struggling to understand at first what your code suppose to do as I didn't know what a spec-framework is.