# In C# does a successful cast operation on reference types ends up creating a new storage location on Heap

Tags: c#, casting

I am looking at C# code taken from MSDN documentation on casting.

In this code `Animal` is a base class and `Giraffe` is a derived class of Animal class.

**Question**: Will implicit and explicit casting on reference types create new Heap storage locations? For example, will variable `a` point to same Heap location that the variable `g` points to, OR `a` will point to a new location on Heap that gets created as a result of implicit casting, and what is the reasoning behind the answer?

My guess is NO because then there would be too much Heap memory being consumed by C# code that is doing implicit casting very often. But, I am not sure of the answer and it's reason.

Also, for the explicit casting in same code it seems `g2` will point to same location as `g` and so no new Heap location gets created by successful explicit casting operation on reference types.

**Casting operation C# code from MSDN**

```
// Create a new derived type.  
Giraffe g = new Giraffe();  

// Implicit conversion to base type is safe.  
Animal a = g;  

// Explicit conversion is required to cast back  
// to derived type. Note: This will compile but will  
// throw an exception at run time if the right-side  
// object is not in fact a Giraffe.  
Giraffe g2 = (Giraffe) a;
```

**Animal and Giraffe class C# code**

```
class Animal
{
    bool IsFourLegged
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    bool CanSpeak
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class Giraffe : Animal
{
    string Country
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    string StripeColor
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply test this with Object.ReferenceEquals?

Comment: Ok. Let me try. I am curious.

Comment: Logically, the answer has to be no new memory is allocated, or a cast back would simply fail.  But verifying a logical conclusion is a good thing, so go for it.  I would have done so if I wasn't using a tablet.

Comment: It doesn't, it simply initializes the reference to the object.  The runtime includes a check that the cast is in fact valid.  Technically there is a corner-case of user-defined conversion operators that can do more than that but surely not what you had in mind.

Comment: @jmoreno, thanks for your answer. Yes, casting on reference types does NOT create new HEAP storage location since `Object.ReferenceEquals` returns true a and g, as well as a and g2. If you want, post it as an answer and I can mark it. Here is the link to code you can try online for verifying this fact: https://dotnetfiddle.net/o07tIl

Comment: @jmoreno, if one thinks about it logically, any object-oriented programming language should not be creating new Heap locations on casting else memory needed would be huge and people will stop using that programming language.

Comment: It is depend on conversion type. For reference conversion: *Reference conversions, implicit or explicit, never change the referential identity of the object being converted.* [link](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/conversions.md). For other type of conversions result can be different.

Comment: @HansPassant, Even though `a` points to `g`, the C# runtime will make sure that some parts of HEAP location for `g` will not be accessible to `a`. For example, `a` would not have the property `StripeColor`. I am not sure how C# will reconcile this fact when `a` it points to same Heap location.

Comment: That is what the runtime check is all about, it guarantees that StripeColor is in fact present.  If not then you'll get an exception.  The C# compiler is not heavily involved with this, other than to check that the cast is not completely nonsensical.  It steps in early when you try to cast an apple to a giraffe.

Comment: @HansPassant. ok that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: The runtime does not try to enforce the negative. `a` can't access `StripeColor` because it doesn't know to even try to do so except in the context of a `Giraffe`.  The compiler knows how a type accesses its data, the runtime ensures that an object is of a given type.  `a` can **only** access a `StripeColor` through a reference to a `Giraffe`.  The compiler doesn't care if it is actually a `Giraffe` or not, it leaves that up to the runtime, it just outputs the correct access, the runtime doesn't care what properties or methods exist, only that the types are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not create a new managed object instance. It will just create a new reference (on the call stack, or maybe in a CPU register) to the *same* instance.

Of course I am talking about casts between two reference types (where one is a base class of the other, or where at least one is an interface type), called *reference conversions* by the C# spec. Other kinds of casts are different.

---

As pointed out in the comments, a user-defined conversion operator may also exist between two `class` types (only when neither is a base class of the other). Such a cast is not a reference conversion, of course, and a different instance (or null) is returned! Commenter's example:

```
string str = "Name";
XName name = str;
```

The last line creates a new object instance of type `XName` (or re-uses an existing `XName` instance it may have). In any case, an `XName` can never be the same instance as a `string`! This conversion could really do anything because it is really just a method call (as seen by the runtime), to the member [`public static implicit operator XName(string expandedName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.op_implicit.aspx), actually named `op_Implicit` or similar within the CIL.

Comment: You mean a new memory location on stack would be created that would contain the pointer to the same original object on Heap

Comment: Not every cast between two reference types can be called *reference conversion*: `XName name = "Name"`. Both `string` and `XName` are reference types, but this is not reference conversion.

Comment: @Sunil Yes. Or maybe the "place" in the stack was allocated when control entered the method whose local variable it is. Then when we assign to the variable, it is checked that the cast is legal (in case of downcasting), and if so, the "reference" (i.e. an integer "pointing" to the memory address) is simply copied.

Comment: `string` to `XName` conversion not always create new instance of `XName` type. It obligated to return the same `XName` instance for two equal strings, [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xname#xname-objects-are-atomized).

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks, I edited my answer even more (it has become a complicated answer to a simple question, but it is quite precise now, I would say).

Answer (score 2):

Short version: Object.ReferenceEquals will show that the cast does not create a new object, just another reference to the same object.

Update: I originally thought this might be possible by implementing an explicit conversion if you wanted to make it happen for some reason, but it is not -- the code won't compile.  The error message is:

```
CS0553: User-defined conversion `Giraffe.explicit operator  
Animal(Giraffe)' cannot convert to or from a base class
```

https://ideone.com/G1k7Q2

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17459267/234954 which references the c# spec...

Comment: The rules of C# do not allow a user-defined conversion operator (`implicit` or `explicit`) to be defined between reference types for which an ordinary _reference conversion_ would already apply.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen It is possible to define user conversion, which would partially overlap with reference conversion: `class C<T> { public static implicit operator T (C<T> i) => default(T); }`. Here `int i = new C<int>();` will use user conversion, while `IEnumerable e = new C<IEnumerable>();` will refuse to compile and `IEnumerable e = (IEnumerable) new C<IEnumerable>();` throw exception in runtime. Although `T Convert<T>(C<T> i) => i;` will always use user conversion, even for `Convert(new C<IEnumerable>())`.

Comment: @PetSerAl I see, there is a loophole for a type parameter that may be a reference type. [You can write funny examples.](https://tio.run/##bY49C8IwEIb3/Iobk0HBjlY72IwKggXnGKMcpElpUm0p/e31rB84ON3d@z48nA4zHfQ4NgHdFQ5diKZMGdNWhQAb6GF47/mqyGA5RVVzsqghRBVpYFnRhRF8ZWoVfQ0F8IlGAesMzuaiGht5IdKvTJIpX8ls8rO36FXtWf8Jbh7PsFPouKBw4ltYgzN3kFzQlxK6BQVtynLvgrdmfqwxmi06w58NsY21RBKYEMil@M8mP@zAhnF8AA)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Nice one. I did not expect it would allow implicit cast in `D y1 = x;` case.